# Use test/unit with anonymous TestCase

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, anonymous, anonymous-class

### This question belongs zu test-unit version 2.5.3

## Problem solved with test-unit version 2.5.4

I have a test with many anonymous TestCases. It worked with test-unit 2.5.0, but the actual version 2.5.3 produces an error.

When I run this test:

```
gem 'test-unit', ">=2.5.2"
require 'test/unit'
Class.new( Test::Unit::TestCase ) do
  def test_add
    assert_equal( 2, 1+1)
  end
end
```

no test is executed and I get the error `undefined method sub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` in `testrunner.rb:361` (I use the actual test-unit-gem 2.5.3).

With a name for the TestCase, the problem disappears:

```
gem 'test-unit'
require 'test/unit'
X = Class.new( Test::Unit::TestCase ) do
  def test_add
    assert_equal( 2, 1+1)
  end
end
```

In my real problem, I generate many TestCases. So I have a situation like:

```
gem 'test-unit'
require 'test/unit'
2.times {
  X = Class.new( Test::Unit::TestCase ) do
    def test_add
      assert_equal( 2, 1+1)
    end
  end
}
```

If I execute this I get a warning `already initialized constant X` and the error:
`comparison of Array with Array failed (ArgumentError)` (in collector.rb:48:in sort_by').

My question(s):

- How can I avoid the error?
- Or: How can I create TestCases with dynamic assigned constants?

Comment: I thought I understood your question, and tried to explain why it didnt work... but actually you're right. This version of Test::Unit requires a class with a name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this is down to a change in the latest version of the `test-unit` gem, which now requires a readable name for a class.

Something like this will work

```
gem 'test-unit', ">=2.5.2"
require 'test/unit'

Class.new( Test::Unit::TestCase ) do
  def test_add
    assert_equal( 2, 1+1)
  end

  def self.to_s
    "GeneratedClass"
  end

  def self.name
    to_s
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried `self.name=` and it did not work. But your answer gave me a hint. I need only a redefinition of name: `def self.name;'Name';end`

Comment: I submitted an issue to `test-unit` https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit/issues/49

Comment: this is now fixed on master https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit/commit/186182d75d7c611626cb8556fea6a3d96c3be2f0

Comment: Thanks for your report.
Version 2.5.4 of gem test-unit don't have the error any longer.